# AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute '_transformer_encoder_layer_fwd'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, transformer-model

I got an error corresponding to the title when `batch_first` is set to True in the Pytorch transformer code. When `batch_first = False`, such an error does not appear.
`Torch version 1.9.0+cu111` and `Python version 3.7.12` are used.

The code below belongs to the `TransformerEncoderLayer` class, where the error corresponding to the title occurs.
[A code with an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YmzL.png)

I can't find the `torch._transformer_encoder_layer_fwd` function even in the pytorch official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because the function `_transformer_encoder_layer_fwd` is not available in PyTorch v1.9.

Switching to the latest torch v1.12 solved the issue for me.